# MATLAB Plotting Error with symbols

Tags: matlab, plot

I am using the code below and am trying to plot a velocity and acceleration curve after differentiation of a position function but I am getting errors. Could someone give me a hand?

```
clc,clear,close all 

t=0:.0001:2*pi/150;
theta= (150*t) ;
r=.2.*cos(theta)+sqrt(.75^2 - (.2.*sin(theta)).^2);
plot(t,r)

hold on

syms t

theta= (150*t);
r=.2.*cos(theta)+sqrt(.75^2 - (.2.*sin(theta)).^2);
v=diff(r,t);
a=diff(r,t,2);

t=0:.0001:2*pi/150;

plot(t,v);
plot(t,a);

hold off
```

Comment: Please post the code which causes the error.

Comment: please see the above post now

Comment: You posted the code, but you didn't post the error.  Where is the error happening?

Comment: Error using plot
Conversion to double from sym is not possible.

Error in BMEG311_HW4 (line 19)
plot(t,v);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason why you're getting errors is because when you are using `diff`, you are using it **symbolically**.  When you're plotting stuff, you need to get the numerical output.  As such, you'll need an additional call to [`subs`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/subs.html), plus a cast using `double` if you want to get this working.  So:

```
syms t;

theta= (150*t);
r=.2.*cos(theta)+sqrt(.75^2 - (.2.*sin(theta)).^2);
v=diff(r,t);
a=diff(r,t,2);

%// Change
t_vec=0:.0001:2*pi/150;
v = double(subs(v, t, t_vec));
a = double(subs(a, t, t_vec));

hold on;

%// Change
plot(t_vec,v);
plot(t_vec,a);

hold off
```